# Badge idea: Magnet / Attractor / Great Attractor

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, badge-request

I got this idea when I looked at one of my old questions [here](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/18476/6143). I was surprised to see it got protected by Community♦ about five months back. It seems it *attracted* lots of people who found it interesting enough to want to answer, hence the badge names.

Possible rules:

> `Magnet` : Bronze
>
> Awarded once, for the first question that gets protected, provided it didn't get closed within [insert timespan ... a week?] of getting protected (to save bad questions that get protected for a reason from being awarded for it).
>
> `Attractor` : Silver
>
> Awarded once, for the 10th question that gets protected, provided it didn't get closed within [insert timespan] of getting protected.
>
> `Great Attractor` : Gold
>
> Awarded for the 25th question that gets protected, provided it didn't get closed within [insert timespan] of getting protected.

Unfortunately I haven't had the time to look at the data explorer to check if the numerics (1st, 10th, 25th) are reasonable or if they should be different.

What I like about this is that it's not really something you can "work towards" in the way you can do with any of the participation badges, but it's more someting that will surprise you, a bit like the Popular/Notable/Famous Question badges ;-)

Comment: Love the name, dislike the idea.

Comment: I could buy that we want questions to get more than one answer. I don't see why we would use protection as a marker there, just count the upvoted answers and award badges to questions with lots of them if that's a useful goal we're falling short on. What's the point of them needing protection though other than that means they are spam targets. I'd think you'd want to give badges to questions that **didn't** attract spam answers i.e. those that have multiple answers but **aren't** protected.

Comment: @RobertLongson If you add some quality criterium to those lots of answers, that might not even be such a bad idea. But of course I agree protection is a very bad indicator of question quality.

Answer (score 11):

Having your question automatically protected by Community is a sign that you have attracted lots of attention to your question, yes. But what kind of attention is it that you have attracted?

It is a good chance that your question have attracted bad answers that have been deleted (which is what protecting questions is normally used to prevent). In the process of deleting these answers, it is very likely that the community (the users, not the automatic bot) protects the question before the Community bot gets a chance to.

Having your question protected is not an achievement, really.

There are a lot of users that are able to protect questions, and when a user protect a question that leads to Community being unable to do it.

There are already badges for getting a lot of views on your question, and for having it reach a certain score, those badges do their job far better than this idea.

Comment: To further expand on this, protection is not at all an indicator of how many people a question attracted. It could have attracted as little as three users who just all decided to post crappy answers that got deleted. It's a tool to prevent low-quality answers, not a quantifier of anything.

Answer (score 5):

I am against this.

Whether a question gets protected depends on two things:

- How many views it gets.
- How likely a viewer is to post a low-quality answer.

We already have a badge for the first factor and those questions for which the second factor is high contain:

- Questions that are attractive to spammers, in particular resource requests.
- Questions that are almost *primarily opinion-based* and thus attract a lot of answers from visitors who do not know how to write a good answer.

While asking such questions is not necessarily a bad behaviour per se, it is certainly not worth awarding. At best you are awarding something random here – you could as well award a badge for having asked 20 questions with a view count that is a prime number at a given time.

Comment: The quality issue was my initial thought as well but [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/358669) doesn't seem to support that hypothesis

Comment: @rene: What does this query show me?

Comment: It shows the count per score for questions that are protected by the community user

Comment: My conclusion: not many low scoring questions are protected....

Comment: @rene: Half of the protected questions have a score of 10 or lower. Also, as a high number of views begets both, protection and a high number of votes, this does not surprise me. But there already is a badge for high views – this is about protected question without these. (I amended my answer to clarify this.)